# Is it legal for a restaurant to not accept cash?

Tags: united-states, virginia, legal-tender

I recently went to [Sweetgreen](http://www.sweetgreen.com/) (a make your own salad place) for the first time. When I got to the end of the counter and was ready to pay, I tried to hand the cashier a $20, but he said "I'm sorry sir, we don't accept cash".

I was really taken aback and ended up having to pay with a card. After lunch, I did some research and found out that [Sweetgreen as a chain is going fully cashless in 2017](https://www.fastcompany.com/3061731/sweetgreen-is-going-fully-cashless-in-2017).

Is that legal? Can a restaurant just not accept cash?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When can "exact change" policies be enforced?](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/14140/when-can-exact-change-policies-be-enforced). In particular, stated and referenced in that question: *"Private businesses are free to develop their own policies on whether or not to accept cash unless there is a State law which says otherwise."*

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### [Yes](https://www.federalreserve.gov/faqs/currency_12772.htm)

> This statute means that all United States money as identified above is a valid and legal offer of payment for debts when tendered to a creditor. There is, however, no Federal statute mandating that a private business, a person, or an organization must accept currency or coins as payment for goods or services. Private businesses are free to develop their own policies on whether to accept cash unless there is a state law which says otherwise.

Comment: ... and [at least New Jersey and Pennsylvania are among states that have laws that generally require businesses to accept cash](https://www.philly.com/business/new-jersey-cashless-store-ban-amazon-philadelphia-20190318.html).

Comment: I don't understand this answer, nor the referenced page.  It sounds to me like it's making two statements that contradict each other: first, that cash is valid for all debts, and second, that it's not.

Comment: @DonHatch It's the distinction between payment for a good or service (where legal tender is generally not required to be accepted unless the individual state has a law to the contrary) vs. repayment of a debt (where legal tender is always required to be accepted.) Paying a merchant for a good or service is not repayment of a debt.