Service refuses to accept cash; is this misleading "convenience fee" legal?
A service advertises a price of $12. When the customer tries to pay, the service provider adds a $2.50 convenience fee for using a debit or credit card and refuses to take any other form of payment.
The $12 price was posted, as was the convenience fee.  But is it legal for them to say something costs $12 if there is literally no way to get it for that price?
ETA: This was an in-person purchase.  And yes, I asked to pay in cash and was refused.

Re edit: so they did post the full price payable? How is this different from posting the original price + sales taxes payable separately? In UK the price posted is often without VAT, stating such. (Because business users can reclaim the VAT).

@WeatherVane One difference is that everyone charges sales tax (US) or VAT (UK), so customers don't need any special warning. This is an unusual extra charge that customers would have no reason to expect. It's like the "resort charge" that many hotels tack on, but don't mention in the price list.

@Barmar: while most retail businesses in US are required to charge sales tax at least sometimes, they do not do so for all sales and customers, with often quite complicated rules, so many customers can in fact be surprised. See for example. In addition depending on the whims of legislators there are sometimes temporary 'holidays' for some items, although these are usually pretty well publicized (at least to residents).

@WeatherVane Some states go as far as to prohibit the inclusion of sales tax as part of the displayed price. For example Nevada NRS 372.120.

Is debit/credit card the only payment method, or is there other like prepaid card/electronic money/bank transfer?

@AndrewT. Debit/credit is the only method of payment available

@WeatherVane In the UK, if prices are quoted excluding VAT, I understand that they also have to be quoted inclusive of VAT (and no less prominently) — specifically for this reason.

@gidds I think you're right, for suppliers that sell to individuals, even if B2B is their main  business. Suppliers that only sells to businesses  do seem to be able to display only ex-VAT prices, even though their customers may have to pay them VAT

Did you receive the service/goods before paying?

It was the municipal dump, so I had to pay Bozo at the little window before accessing the landfill.  I suppose I COULD have refused and said I didn't want to pay the fee ... but then where would I take my trash?

You have the right to not pay and not use their services; your trash is your problem. If you're persistent enough you can get the fee waived but it sounds like that business is okay with the deceptive practices. This scenario reminds me of a YouTube video I watched recently about Dollar General's predatory practices. In short, fines are the cost of doing business. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uE5THiD-kTk

@MonkeyZeus you are correct, although all the nearby municipalities require residency permits so this is the only place I could go.  I've given up the idea of fighting it

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

@nuggethead Write to your elected officials. A law is meaningless if not enforced. The municipal dump is not browsing law.stackexchange.com and trying to see if their actions were legal on a given day.

united-states
I think this may be legal at the moment. In October 2023, the FTC announced a proposed rule to prohibit "junk fees" that are not disclosed upfront. They held an unformal hearing on this in April 2024.
But as far as I've been able to tell, this new rule has not yet been enacted. So "surprise" fees at checkout time are still legal.

This is incorrect, for the US, when you're specifically talking about refusing to take cash payment and junk/service fees. (If the customer was able to optionally avoid the fees e.g. by paying cash, that would be different. But in this case case the merchant/agency refuses to take cash payment.)

Isn't it illegal to not accept cash as a payment? I have no idea about the USA, but in my country you're legally obliged to accept cash as money. It's kind of the fundamental feature of it, after all...

Does this mean sales-tax not being included in the price will come to an end? If so, great news?

As far as I can remember, of the thirty countries I've visited, USA is the only one that doesn't reveal the actual price before purchase.  Grrr.

@Neinstein It depends on the state. See https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/31224/can-someone-deny-cash-as-the-payment-method/104608#104608

@billpg No, I don't think sales tax that's required by the government is considered a "junk fee".

@Barmar I was thinking of them more as a "surprise" fee. (Also tips but that's another issue.)

@billpg The point of the legislation is to make it easy for consumers to compare prices of different vendors. Since sales tax percentage is the same for all vendors, you don't need to see it upfront to compare.

united-kingdom
It is not legal to charge a surcharge for paying with a credit or debit card unless the card is a commercial one. This rule is set out in Regulation 6A(1)(a) of the Consumer Rights (Payment Surcharges) Regulations 2012:

(1) A payee must not charge a payer any fee in respect of payment by
means of —
(a) a payment instrument which —
(i) is a card-based payment instrument as defined in Article 2(20) of
Regulation (EU) 2015/751 of the European Parliament and of the Council
of 29th April 2015 on interchange fees for card-based payment
transactions ; and
(ii) is not a commercial card as defined in Article 2(6) of that
Regulation


Sorry, I neglected to include the US tag.  This is in the states, not the UK

@nuggethead That's fine, this site encourages multi-jurisdiction answers in case it's of use to future readers. Hopefully someone will give you a US-based answer.

IIR at one time (1980s?) either British Telecom or British Gas made a charge for paying the bill by any means :)... because they used a third party billing agent?

Is this really a credit card surcharge? It's the only way to pay, so this is simply part of the charge, not a charge for choosing to pay with a card.

Wow. This is good to know, because there are places that charge a fee. Theatre/concert tickets come to mind, as an example

Theatre/concert tickets don't generally add a card fee; they use an online ticket provider and they charge a fee. If you pay at the box office you can't be charged a card fee and won't be charged the online fee.

No
australia
The Australian Consumer Law requires a) an all inclusive price to be stated and b) some mechanism for actually paying that all inclusive price.
It is not unlawful to charge surcharges for different payment types provided they are reflecting the actual cost to the business of accepting that payment. That is, if investigated, the business must be able to demonstrate that the surcharge is rationally related to the cost of the payment method. So, if the credit card provider charges say 0.7%, a surcharge of say 1% is probably justifiable; over 10% as here probably isn’t.
Notwithstanding, there must still be a method of paying the all inclusive price and no more. So, if a business charges for every payment method, the advertised price must include the surcharge for the least expensive payment method.

Although you're to the best of my knowledge correct, it is quite possible for a $2.50 fee to be proportionate. Depending on the industry, and the history of the merchant, fees of over ten percent (plus a non-trivial flat fee) are not that uncommon. The hypothetical service might have been rental of an adult film, or even a donation to charity, or the merchant might have had a really bad history of chargebacks.

The first line and last paragraph are mismatching with OP's question, where no payment method without the charge was accepted.

@R..GitHubSTOPHELPINGICE: This answer says that the practice described in the question is not legal: that's why it starts with "no". It then goes on to explain what the legal requirements are.

Oh, my bad - I read the question at the end of the post rather than the subject line, and the yes/no are reversed,,,

germany
This is... complicated.
What you describe would be illegal, because

Bürgerliches Gesetzbuch (BGB)
§ 270a Vereinbarungen über Entgelte für die Nutzung bargeldloser Zahlungsmittel
Eine Vereinbarung, durch die der Schuldner verpflichtet wird, ein Entgelt für die Nutzung einer SEPA-Basislastschrift, einer SEPA-Firmenlastschrift, einer SEPA-Überweisung oder einer Zahlungskarte zu entrichten, ist unwirksam

Translation:

Civil Code (BGB)
§ Section 270a Agreements on charges for the use of cashless means of payment
An agreement obliging the debtor to pay a fee for the use of a SEPA core direct debit, a SEPA business-to-business direct debit, a SEPA credit transfer or a payment card is invalid

Bascially says that I can pay with my German Debit Card and no business is allowed to charge a fee for that. They do not have to accept my card, but if they do, they cannot charge extra.
However
It is legal to charge extra for services that in turn charge your account by the same (SEPA) means. So for example if you put your card as a payment option into Paypal or SofortÜberweisung, services that charge the seller an extra fee over what a SEPA transaction would cost, it is legal for the seller to charge the buyer/consumer extra for usage of those services.
I say it is complicated, because the highest court ruled on it, after lower instances went back and forth on it:
https://www.bundesgerichtshof.de/SharedDocs/Pressemitteilungen/DE/2021/2021067.html

Is it legal to not offer a way to pay the advertised price though?

No, in Germany, the "price" has to include everything. The only exception is deposits on bottles or the likes, that you actually get back after returning the empty bottle. Because that is not something you "pay" if you get it back. But everything else (and yes, that includes all taxes) has to be given up front as the "price". So if you only accept paypal and you want $5 for paypal, your product has to be priced at plus five dollar. It can be listed on the invoice, how much of the price is taxes, and how much of it is paypal extra, but your price has to be what I have to pay to buy it.
